# Unable to find .aws directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

By default python 2.75 is installed in my machine and I installed boto3 and awcli using `pip install awscli boto3 -U --ignore-installed six` command. And it got installed fine, I checked,but there I can't find .aws directory in my home directory. I tried to find using locate and find commands but no use. I want to know where that directory is to add a new profile to the credentials file in the .aws directory

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You have to run `aws configure` to have it create the `~/.aws` directory.

Comment: Thanks I was able to do that using your answer, Can't upvote your answer due to my reputation : )

Answer (score 5):

.aws hidden directory so you need to write command ls -a. This command will provide all hidden folders.

Answer (score 1):

Also I found that .aws folder gets created in the adminstrator account(user) so just take that into account while working ,as if you don't have admin power then login through that and then check like in C:\Users\Administrator.aws